# Pass Element to Event Listener Callback Function

Tags: javascript, callback, addeventlistener, event-listener

In the following code:

```
document.getElementById( 'elem' ).addEventListener( 'blur', function() {
    myScript();
});
```

How can I pass the document.getElementById( 'elem' ) object to myScript()? I was thinking of something like the keyword "this," so I can then act on the element in the callback function.

Comment: Yes, use `this`. `document.getElementById( 'elem' ).addEventListener( 'blur', function() { myScript(this); });`

Comment: `console.log(this)` inside your callback will reveal that `this` equals your element

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### You have four ways to pass the object `this`

**Bind the `this` object and call the function:**

*This approach should be used if you need to execute some logic before `myScript()` execution*

```js
function myScript() {
  console.log(this.id);
}

document.getElementById('elem').addEventListener('click', function() {
  myScript.bind(this)();
});
```

```html
<button id="elem">Click me!</button>
```

**Call the function `myScript` using function `call`:**

*This approach should be used if you need to execute some logic before `myScript()` execution*

**Also read about function [`Function.prototype.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).**

```js
function myScript() {
  console.log(this.id);
}

document.getElementById('elem').addEventListener('click', function() {
  myScript.call(this);
});
```

```html
<button id="elem">Click me!</button>
```

**Pass the function directly:**

```js
function myScript() {
  console.log(this.id);
}

document.getElementById('elem').addEventListener('click', myScript);
```

```html
<button id="elem">Click me!</button>
```

**Or pass the object `this`:**

```js
function myScript(element) {
  console.log(element.id);
}

document.getElementById('elem').addEventListener('click', function() {
  myScript(this); //Here you will need to use the param.
});
```

```html
<button id="elem">Click me!</button>
```

## Resource

- [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)
- [`Function.prototype.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: You should also mention `myScript.call(this)` method ;)

Answer (score 1):

Further to the answer from Ele, you should prefer the binding method. As dfsq said in the comment, you can go

```
element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    myScript(element);
}
```

However, using an anonymous function like this means you won't be able to remove the event listener.

```
const element = document.getElementById('elem');
// creates a new function instance with element bound as first arg
const eventListenerCallback = myScript.bind(null, element);
element.addEventListener('click', eventListenerCallback);

function myScript(element, event) {
    element.setAttribute('data-clicked', 'true');
    // remove the event listener once it has been clicked
    element.removeEventListener('click', eventListenerCallback);
}
```